# Drop down sub menu not working

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation, superfish

http://www.lumivase.com/

on the above site. The menu disappears when trying to use sub menus of the menu. I.e on the site menu goto market research plus>resource center>(if it hasn't closed yet) then go to A dozen problems with...

I have tried reverting the css to the original styles and although this does completely mess up the menu widths the problem still exists even with the original css coding.

Attached is my current css file, If you could direct me to what rule controls the sub menu of the menu that would be great.

```
/* -------------------[ Top Navigation ]------------------- */

#topnav {

    width: 970px;

    padding: 1px 0 0;

    margin: 0 auto;

    background:url(images/navbg.gif) top left;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px; rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px; rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px; rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    }



#topnav .limit {

    width:970px;

    margin:0 auto;

    padding:0;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px; rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px; rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px; rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    }


#topnav ul {

    height: auto;

    width:970px;

    list-style: none;

    padding: 0 0px;

    margin: 0 auto;

    float:left;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px; rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px; rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px; rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    }



#topnav ul a, #topnav ul a:link, #topnav ul a:visited {

    height: auto;

    display: block;

    text-decoration: none;

    padding: 0 10px;

    margin:0 auto;

    color:#fff;

    overflow:hidden;

    float:left;

    }



#topnav ul a:hover, #topnav ul a:active  {

    background:#0A1F33;

    height: auto;

    }



#topnav li {

    height: auto;

    line-height:40px;

    float: left;

    }



#topnav li ul {

    float:left;

    z-index:9999;

    position: absolute;

    left: -999em;

    height: auto;

    width: 400px;

    margin-top: 35px;

    padding: 0 10px;

    border-top:1px solid #f5f5f5;

    background:#0A1F33;

    }



#topnav li li {

    height: auto;

    line-height:30px;

    border-bottom:1px solid #000;

    }



#topnav ul li ul a, #topnav ul li ul a:link, #topnav ul li ul a:visited {

    height: auto;

    width:380px;

    float:left;

    }



#topnav ul li ul a:hover, #topnav ul li ul a:active  {

    height: auto;

    background:#000;

    }



#topnav li ul ul {

    height: auto;

    border:0;

    margin: -30px 0 0 400px;

    height: auto;

    }



#topnav li:hover ul ul, #topnav li:hover ul ul ul, #topnav li.sfhover ul ul, #topnav li.sfhover ul ul ul {

    height: auto;

    left: -999em;

    height: auto;

    }



#topnav li:hover ul, #topnav li li:hover ul, #topnav li li li:hover ul, #topnav li.sfhover ul, #topnav li li.sfhover ul, #topnav li li li.sfhover ul {

    left: auto;

    height: auto;

    }



#topnav li:hover, #topnav li.sfhover {

    background:#0A1F33;

    height: auto;

    }
```

Comment: The dropdowns are not pure CSS. It appears you are using jQuery and "superfish". Check out the superfish javascript code: `$('#topnav ul, #nav ul').superfish({ .....`.

Comment: ummm any ideas where about that file would be located?? I am not that smart overall :(

Comment: If you view the source code of the page you linked, it starts on line 75. That being said, the menus seem to work for me. Each menu closes if your mouse is not over that menu itself or its parent trigger. This is one reason I often find nested drop-downs a little irritating from a user interface point of view.

Comment: Well I just tried it in IE 10/9 idk what the newest one is. and it works perfectly, So in firefox it has issues? Also I did find the file you where talking about with the sucker fish script and I have absolutely no idea how to change that code to make it work better in firefox. Any advice you can give while the firefox issue?

Comment: Works perfectly fine with chrome too grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

Comment: I'm not clear which problem you're referring to. The only thing I notice is that it doesn't seem to be respecting your `delay` setting. But I'm not familiar with suckerfish or superfish. You might want to try upgrading jQuery and superfish to more recent versions.

Comment: Well thanks for that man, That at least gives me something else to look into. Thanks for the help/tips.